# How can we add custom extended field on top of the screen while new contact creation?

Tags: outbound-email, audience-manager

I have added a new custom extended field in audience manager contact creation window. But I want my custom required field on top of this screen. And Can we move my custom field to General tab.[image]

Comment: Are you using the Import Source field at all? If not why not renaming its label to Brand and use that, it will be then displayed 2nd. The fields are displayed in the order of the columns in the Tridion_cm_email database table CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS. However, it is hard to change the order of columns in SQL Server/Oracle, so working on a UI extension may be an alternative. Else in a not supported way you could modify the Stored Procedure which is reading contact details, but this will not work anymore after an upgrade...

Comment: Did any of the answers posted below help you with this question? If so, please accept one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is determined by the database. So if you can change the order there, you can have it show up at the top.

You cannot put it on the General tab, as that's for the built-in fields that aren't customizable.

Of course you could try to do something like that in a GUI extension, but I doubt it would be worth the investment.

(FYI, the next version will likely have the ability to move the fields up and down as you wish)

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation about [Custom Contact extension](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-E4596A79-2FD5-43DF-9BA9-F6B304D3EFAF).